# google maps api -> set max cruising speed

Tags: performance, google-maps, limit

how can I set the max cruising speed, if I calc a new route?

I use the Google Maps API at my site for trucks and want to set a "max speed limit" by 80 km/h. Any idea?

Comment: That's my exact requirement too. What's your suggested workaround? Bearing in mind that trucks also take longer to accelerate and decelerate, maybe we can just multiply the Google travel time by a standard factor?

Answer (score 1):

The Google Maps API does not provide speedlimit information or filtering, so you can't.

Answer (score -1):

It should. Any travel guidance system which provides a time needs to take all sorts of factors into the calculation - just see how effective TomTom IQ routes is! It uses not only speed limits but actual real-time speed data gathered from Tomtom users. Also, I tow a caravan and so a 70mph speed on a UK motorway is not applicable, but I can set a maximum speed of 60mph (the max in the UK on motorways, if towing), which makes the transit times pretty close to reality most of the time. Google maps times are meaningless.
KC

Comment: This does not answer the questions at all.